# C# variable or array with number range (example. 1 - 100)

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010, variables

I'm fairly new to C# and I'm doing a school project, i need to figure out how to get a variable or an array with numbers from 1 to 100 without entering every single number in an array for example `int[] numbersArray {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...};` because that takes a long time and doesn't look very efficient.

I'm using C# Visual Studio Express 2010. It would mean alot to me if you could answer this for me. I'm gonna be using it in an if statement like so:

```
if(numbersArray.Contains(numbersInput))
{
    Console.WriteLine("numbersInput was a number from 1 to 100")
}
```

Comment: If all you're going to be doing is checking if a number is between 1 and 100 you should do `if (numbersInput >= 1 && numbersInput <= 100) Console.WriteLine("numbersInput was a number from 1 to 100")` instead.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Range` to create a range of numbers:

```
int[] arr = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray();
```

Comment: *Note:* you need .NET 3.5 and above for `Enumerable.Range`.  If you're on an older .NET, you won't have it.

Comment: Thanks for the help i would vote up but i only have 1 rep point so i can't, thanks man.

Comment: @Realitiez Glad I could help - you should be able to vote up soon, btw - you got some more rep from this question ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you're assignment is just to print a message if the input is within a range you simply can do this:

```
if (numbersInput >= 1 && numbersInput <= 100)
    Console.WriteLine("numbersInput was a number from 1 to 100");
```

But if you really need to create an array with numbers 1..100 you can use a `for`-loop:

```
var numbersArray = new int[100];
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    numbersArray[i - 1] = i;
```

Or simply use a little Linq:

```
var numbersArray = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. All answers are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you could just use a for loop with the iterator of the loop as the counter:

```
int[] numbersArray = new int[100] // initialise array to 100 elements.
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    numbersArray[i - 1] = i;  // note we are using 0-based indexing to access elements of the array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other way...

```
int[] arr = new int[100];
for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
{
    arr[i]=i+1;
}
```